# Splitting a String Variable in Windows Bat File

Tags: batch-file

I am executing a command that returns a string output in format - 'SessionID:xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx'. I want to split this SessionID string based on ':' and store the later part in a variable called Session_ID.

I am trying the below code:

```
 @echo off
    
    echo Changing the Directory to Blue Prism Automate
    cd C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate

    echo Triggering CSM Validation Process and Storing the Session ID
    for /f %%i in ('AutomateC.exe /resource BWD14195034 /port 8215 /sso /run "CSMValidationInput"') do set RESULT=%%i
    
    For /f "delims=:" %%A in ("%RESULT%") do Set Session_ID = %%A
    
    echo %Session_ID%
    
    Pause
```

Upon executing I am getting 'Echo is OFF'. Why am i not able to split my string and get the Session ID?

Comment: you created a variable `%session_ID %` note the space? Change `Session_ID = %%A` to `Session_ID=%%A`

Comment: @Gerhard thanks made that correction but the command i am executing returns a string like 'Session:xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx'. This code is storing 'Session' in Session_ID after the split. I want to store the latter part

Comment: Why not just use Substring modification to remove the sessionID: component of the string? `Set "result=%result:SessionID:=%"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using two [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop)s:

```batch-file
@Echo Off

Echo Changing the current directory to Blue Prism Automate.
CD /D "%ProgramFiles%\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate" 2>NUL||GoTo :EOF

Echo Triggering CSM validation and storing the session ID as a variable.
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%G In ('AutomateC.exe /resource BWD14195034 /port 8215 /sso /run "CSMValidationInput"')Do Set "%%G_ID=%%H"

Echo(%Session_ID%

Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code. Note double quotes around path, `/d` switch with `cd`, removal of spaces when `set`ting variables and then using `tokens=2*` to get the second part of the split string. where `token=1` would be everything before the `:`

```
@echo off
  
echo Pushing to 'Blue Prism Automate' Directory
cd /d "C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate"

echo Triggering CSM Validation Process and Storing the Session ID
for /f %%i in ('AutomateC.exe /resource BWD14195034 /port 8215 /sso /run "CSMValidationInput"') do set RESULT=%%i
    
For /f "tokens=2* delims=:" %%A in ("%RESULT%") do Set "Session_ID=%%A" 
echo %Session_ID% 
Pause
```

I would have however used `pushd` instead:

```
@echo off
  
echo Changing the Directory to Blue Prism Automate
pushd "C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate"

echo Triggering CSM Validation Process and Storing the Session ID
for /f %%i in ('AutomateC.exe /resource BWD14195034 /port 8215 /sso /run "CSMValidationInput"') do set RESULT=%%i
popd
For /f "tokens=2* delims=:" %%A in ("%RESULT%") do Set "Session_ID=%%A" 
echo %Session_ID% 
Pause
```